# Can't jcmd, jps or jstat cassandra process within the docker container

Tags: linux, jvm, jstat

```
    $ jcmd -l 
    418 sun.tools.jcmd.JCmd -l

    $ jstat -gcutil -t 10 250ms 1
    10 not found
```

I am aware of the [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8073858) in jdk related to attaching jstat as root to a process running as a different user.

Here, this docker container has one user root and as can be seen below from the ps command, cassandra is running under root.

```
 $ whoami
 root
```

I have tried to do the following:
*$ sudo -u root jcmd -l*

Any help is appreciated.

Docker container is debian:jessie 
running java version:
openjdk version "1.8.0_66-internal"

Here's the output of ps -ef:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 17:40 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /run.sh
root        10     1 11 17:40 ?        00:02:25 java -ea -javaagent:/usr/share/c
root       375     0  0 17:49 ?        00:00:00 bash
root       451   375  0 18:00 ?        00:00:00 ps -ef
```

Aside: jstack successfully dumps out the stack traces of the threads.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know at least two possible reasons why this can happen.

1. Java is run with `-XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem` option. This option helps sometimes to reduce JVM safepoint pauses, but it also makes JVM invisible to `jps` and `jstat`. This is a very likely case, because you are running Cassandra, and recent Cassandra has this option [ON by default](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9242).
2. Java process has a different mount namespace, so that `/tmp` of Java process is not physically the same directory as `/tmp` of your shell. The directory `/tmp/hsperfdata_root` must be accessible in order to use `jps` or `jstat`. This is also a plausible reason since you are using docker containers.

Comment: (2.)  probably is not the case for me as java.io.tmpdir hasn't been explicitly set.  Sorry been swamped.  Will run cassandra without PerfDisablesSharedMem later this evening and mark this as the right answer if I can validate it.

Comment: @hs20400 `java.io.tmpdir` does not matter at all. I was talking about [Linux namespaces](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html). Containers often make use of namespaces to provide a kind of isolation between processes, including isolation of directory structure.

Comment: This may be an entirely different thread but just to clarify ... would running `readlink /proc/3528/ns/pid` on the pid of my cassandra process and `readlink /proc/3528/ns/pid` on the pid of my shell where i am running jstat from and comparing the symlinks be sufficient to see if they are in the same namespace?

Comment: @hs20400 Yes, but `mnt` instead of `pid`. Check that `readlink /proc/$$/ns/mnt` and `readlink /proc/<java_pid>/ns/mnt` return the same.

Comment: In my case it turned out to be case 1 of @apangin suggestions.

Comment: Interesting case for me the user has no name (`whoami: cannot find name for user ID xxxxx`), so the JVM . doesn't create `/tmp/hsperfdata_$USERNAME` directory (and `bool UsePerfData                              = true` flag is enabled).